# My external links are not working with the built Cordova Android

Tags: cordova, apk, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on an Android application with cordova phonegap and included in my files I used Bootstrap and jQuery but after build the app and installing to my device it only shows me a simple index.

HTML page which looks like the Bootstrap and jQuery I used isn't working and I can't even navigate to any other page because the button on the first page is not working, please how do I go about this to make my Bootstrap and jQuery work with other external links like fontawesome.

This is my config.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.hp.portal" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name> Student portal</name>
    <description>
        A sample Student Portal App
    </description>
    <author email="suzanejura@gmail.com" href="http://cordova.io">
       Suzan Ejura
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Did you download the bootstrap 'dist' folder into your project?

Comment: yes i did. i also downloaded the jquery too but still after building and installing the apk it still gives the same result